# AS2 Valve Query number connected of players does not show for steam/epic cross player servers

Tags: steam

I am querying ARK Survival server with Server Queries(https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries) and I've noticed something odd, since it is a cross player game from steam and epic, epic players does not show in the A2S_INFO and A2S_PLAYER query.

Example from: https://github.com/Crytilis/A2S/tree/master

```
var ip ="109.230.214.41"; //oficial ark server
var port = 27017 
var players= Players.Query(ip, port, 5)

foreach (var player in players)
{
response += $"[Name] {player.Name}\n"
}
```

The same code does not list player when i am connected with epic, but list my player when connected with steam account.

Look into Epic Online Services (EOS) I could not find anything related to number of players connected.

Is there a way to find out how many players are connected to a sever that supports AS2 Valve Query that is a epic/steam server?